# In SAS, how to do frequency tables for only certain values of the 'by' variable?

Tags: sas, frequency-analysis

I have a set of values in a by variable; but I only need to do frequencies by certain of those values, not all.

My code is:

```
proc freq data=cath.characterlabels (where=(location in ("City of ABC", "City of 
ABD", "City of ABY", "City of example", "City of example2", "City of 
example3")));
by location;
run;
```

But I get an error:

```
NOTE: BY line has been truncated at least once.
 NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
   Please rate the extent to which each of the following aspects of your space or facility 
meets your needs: The location of 
   y=City of 
 NOTE: There were 427 observations read from the data set CATH.CHARACTERLABELS.
   WHERE location in ("City of ABC", "City of 
ABD", "City of ABY", "City of example", "City of example2", "City of 
example3");
```

And it doesn't give me the correct frequency tables by the locations I want. It just runs each variable's frequency table as though I hadn't included a by statement.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You asked to do repeated one-way frequencies of every variable for every level of LOCATION.  Is that not what you wanted?  Show an example of what you want.

Comment: Check your data.  You appear to have a location with a spurious value that is `Please rate the extent to which each of the following aspects of your space or facility 
meets your needs: The location of 
   y=City of `